# What's the story behind 小間物屋を開く = to vomit?

Tags: colloquial-language, history

[jisho.org defines](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B0%8F%E9%96%93%E7%89%A9%E5%B1%8B%E3%82%92%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F) [小]{こ}[間]{ま}[物]{もの}[屋]{や}を[開]{ひら}く as "to vomit", "to spew". What's the story behind this funny term? How would you express it in English?

Comment: This is a link about it. https://imidas.jp/idiom/detail/X-05-X-10-7-0003.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the link in the comment indicates 小間物屋 is a vendor who sells a lot of things like cosmetics, everyday goods, etc. They often displays their goods in very spread out manner on a cloth (風呂敷). You can visualize it like thus:

[image]

The expression 小間物屋を開く is a euphemism for puking out so much stuff that it's like you are opening a 小間物屋 and displaying a wide variety of goods. In particular if you are puking out partially digested foods, it would have a particular similarity to goods on display. This expression is also sometimes used as デパートを開く or 八百屋を開く as well as 小間物屋を広げる and 小間物屋を出す, but I think in general this expression and its variants are not very well known/used.

The closest English expression I can think of is ***puking out your guts***.

Sources:

- 隠語大辞典

  - https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%8F%E9%96%93%E7%89%A9%E5%B1%8B
  - https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%8F%E9%96%93%E7%89%A9%E5%BA%97%E3%82%92%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F
- https://imidas.jp/idiom/detail/X-05-X-10-7-0003.html
- https://www.waraerujd.com/blank-830
- Image: https://www.benricho.org/Unchiku/edo-syokunin/01jinrinkinmo/13.html

Comment: That idiom is so disgustingly creative 